# Dell computer slows down due to not charging

Tags: laptop, performance, battery, dell-latitude, charging

I have a Dell Latitude E6420. It currently has this problem where it will be plugged in and not be charging. When it doesn't charge it massively slows down its performance. Sometimes if I wiggle the charging cable for a while I can get it to charge and it runs at normal speed. I know that the problem is with the charging cable and it needs to be fixed.

Is there any temporary solution to make the computer run at normal speed without replacing the charger by maybe adjusting power settings or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is related with the Power Settings in your system.

When you check the Power Options in your system, we can set different state value for processor: On battery and Plugged in.  By default, the value of the Maximum processor state when using battery is lower than plugged in state.

Please change the value as you wished to make the laptop running fast as plugged in.

[image]

**Note**: Please select the active power settings profile in the red box.